# how align div one beside other, and on other div

Tags: html, css

[image]

i tried some codes but, no works anything. 
 would like make this with css, thanks =)

this code i tried, but doesn't work.

```
#left{
float:left;
width:65%;
overflow:hidden;
}
#right{
overflow:hidden;
}
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="left">Left side div</div>
<div id="right">Right side div</div>
</div>
```

i don{t know why this doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution with no floats:

```css
#main {
    width: 200px;                 /* adjust as needed */
    font-size: 0;
}
div div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 60px;                 /* adjust as needed */
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 4px #000; /* cosmetics only */
    background: #eee;               /* cosmetics only */
}

div.h {
    width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">
    <div class="h"></div>
    <div class="h"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

Note: using `font-size: 0` for the container div to avoid the actual whitespace in the markup - can be avoided by removing spaces between elements, of course: `<div>content here...</div><div>other one...</div>`

Answer (score 1):

Add `float:left;` to `#right`, then it should work. Note that you could also use `float:right;` to `#right`, then `#right` would be on the right side. Using `float: left;` for both displays both divs next to each other without any gap.

For reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float

Answer (score 1):

Here's a **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tbnnm812/12/)** that I've quickly created for you. The layout is same as what you had requested and it's responsive as well.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="onetwo">
        <div id="one"></div>
        <div id="two"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="three"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid blue;
    padding: 1% 1%;
    text-align: center;
}
#onetwo {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
#one, #two {
    width: 49%;
    border: 3px solid red;
    height: 50px;
    display: inline-block;
}
#three {
    width: 100%;
    border: 3px solid red;
    height: 50px;
}
@media (max-width: 820px) {
    #one, #two {
        width: 46%;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 240px) {
    #one, #two {
        width: 40%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a note that because of the thick border size, at a certain width, the blocks will collapse on top of each other. Not sure if OP wants to prevent that but either way its a very minor thing. Good answer.

Comment: @aug: Thank you and I noticed that as well. I believe the OP could use `@media-queries` in order to prevent that, please take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/tbnnm812/12/

Answer (score 1):

Try this script, I wrote it on JSfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/xb5vvpzn/1/

HTML

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="top">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="bottom1">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="bottom2">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.main {
    width:400px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:400px;
    padding:10px;
}

.main div {
    display:inline-block;    
}

.top {
    width:396px;
    border: 1px solid #cc0000;
    height:100px;
}

.bottom1, .bottom2 {
    margin-top:10px;
    border: 1px solid #cc0000;
    width:195px;
    height:100px;
}
```